# Qt Application resources are missing in static build

Tags: windows, qt, static

I trying to build Qt application under windows statically but after static build application resources are missing (I use custom icons).

I compiled Qt statically using the following commands:

```sh
configure -opensource -confirm-license -static -platform win32-g++ -opengl desktop -prefix "C:\Qt\5.13.0\mingw73_64-static" -skip webengine -nomake examples
mingw32-make
mingw32-make install
```

Using the dynamic version of Qt, everything works, the icons are missing only when I use static version. Icons in .svg format.
Also I tried to `Q_INIT_RESOURCE` but have the same result :(

Comment: https://falsinsoft.blogspot.com/2018/02/qt-load-resources-from-static-or-shared.html

Comment: @VahagnAvagyan, I think this is not my case. The example shows how to build the resources of a static library. But I am trying to build my application with a static version of Qt.